# Fill complex image with color

Tags: java, graphics, png, fill, edge-detection

Let's say I have a PNG image with transparency, like so:
[image: sword with transparent background]

I want, in Java, to fill only the object with black, like so:
[image: sword filled with black]

This is a fairly trivial process in Photoshop, but this is a process I'd like to repeat frequently, ideally without making a black fill picture for each object I'd like to do it for. I've tried several edge detecting classes but found no success.

How would I accomplish this?

*Additional info: this is going to be a quick-and-dirty way to create shadows. If you can think of a better way, that would solve this problem completely.*

Comment: Would a basic mask on non-transparent pixels work? Also, it is **not** a trivial process in Photoshop; Photoshop makes it ***seem*** like a *trivial* process.

Comment: That's true. The mask could certainly work--how would I generate the mask from the image?

Comment: Could you iterate over each pixel and check the alpha value? If it's not transparent, set the pixel to black?

Comment: That seems likely but I get the sense it might take a long time for large images or multiple images at once. Am I correct and if so--are there ways to improve efficiency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a function that loops through all the pixels and fill them with black color.

```
BufferedImage image = ...
Color fillColor = new Color(0, 0, 0); // Black

for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        int color = image.getRGB(x, y);
        int alpha = (color >> 24) & 0xff;

        if (alpha == 255) {
            image.setRGB(x, y, fillColor.getRGB());
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this will only work on fully opaque pixels. If the image on top contains some transparency, you can also change the condition to be more tolerant: `if (alpha > 127)`. This will fill all pixels that are less than 50% transparent.

Comment: With a couple edits (_alpha != 0_, _fillColor.getRGB()_) it works perfectly for me! Thank you. As I asked meepzh, will this run into efficiency problems with large images or doing several at once?

Comment: Regarding efficiency with large images: you'll probably get better speed and (especially) memory usage with [PNGJ](https://github.com/leonbloy/pngj)

Answer (score 0):

Within Photoshop, you can use something called Actions. [This can get you started](http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/photoshop/ss/basicaction.htm). Since every PNG file's primary layer is called Layer 0, this should work for every file. Record an action where you set the Layer Style of Layer 0 to be colored black. Then save the file and stop recording the Action. Use File >> Automate >> Batch to perform this on many files. I'd recommend saving a backup of the files in case you make a mistake.

Comment: That would be a great way to create a .png file for every image I intended to do this for. Thank you for the link!
However, if I have a prohibitively large number of these images, packaging them in a java project would lead to a large filesize. Would there be a way to do it through a Java operation instead?